# Using "send email" example but not receiving emails

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I used the example api and ran my code. No issues encountered but did not receive my test email. My code is below. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance!

```
       private async void SendMailGraph()
        {

            string graphScope = "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared";
            var graphScopes = graphScope.Split(' ').ToArray();

            // Build a client application.
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(configuration["MicrosoftAppId"])
                        .Build();
            // Create an authentication provider by passing in a client application and graph scopes.
            DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(publicClientApplication, graphScopes);
            // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "lujun@microsoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var saveToSentItems = false;

            await graphClient.Me
                .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
        }
    }
```

I set up debug point before sending the request to graphClient. The message is below

{Microsoft.Graph.Message}

```
AdditionalData: null
Attachments: null
BccRecipients: null
Body: {Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody}
BodyPreview: null
Categories: null
CcRecipients: null
ChangeKey: null
ConversationId: null
ConversationIndex: null
CreatedDateTime: null
Extensions: null
Flag: null
From: null
HasAttachments: null
Id: null
Importance: null
InferenceClassification: null
InternetMessageHeaders: null
InternetMessageId: null
IsDeliveryReceiptRequested: null
IsDraft: null
IsRead: null
IsReadReceiptRequested: null
LastModifiedDateTime: null
MultiValueExtendedProperties: null
ODataType: "microsoft.graph.message"
ParentFolderId: null
ReceivedDateTime: null
ReplyTo: null
Sender: null
SentDateTime: null
SingleValueExtendedProperties: null
Subject: "Meet for lunch?"
ToRecipients: Count = 1
UniqueBody: null
WebLink: null
```

The request sync does not return any response.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug this code and inspect what is happening at each point? Could you include some more detail about the steps you have already attempted in order to resolve this problem? That kind of additional detail will encourage people to respond.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thanks for your reply! I debugged it and updated my question!

Comment: Referring to the same article three years later and getting the same behaviour - emails are in Sent folder, but they are not received by the specified recipients.  I am using Microsoft Developer Program tenant to send the emails from (to test the functionality first), so not sure if that makes a difference - if it does, it should be added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Azure AD tenant does not have an Exchange online license under the O365 subscription. As a result, your tenant does not have the ability to send Email messages.

And you can refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273685/unable-to-send-email-using-graph-api-c-console-by-creating-graphserviceclient/64275137#64275137).

***UPDATE***

This is my test code that little has changed and it works, you can refer to.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace devicecode
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

                string graphScope = "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared";
                var graphScopes = graphScope.Split(' ').ToArray();

                // Build a client application.
                IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                            .Create("My clienid")
                            .Build();

            DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(publicClientApplication, graphScopes);
            // Create an authentication provider by passing in a client application and graph scopes.
                // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

                var message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "mytestaccount"
                        }
                    }
                }
                };

                var saveToSentItems = false;

                await graphClient.Me
                    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

And if the run is successful,you can see the picture below.
[image]

Since you have subscription, so i guess the problem occurred your received account.You can test [send email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1) in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview).

Comment: Hi Chauncy! I checked the reference above. Do you know which license do I need? My Azure AD tenant is "Microsoft" and it already has Office 365 E3 and Office 365 E5. @Chauncy Zhou